# Como cambiar icono APP android studio?

Tags: android

Estoy intentado cambiar el icono de mi app y no se cambia he seguido tutoriales y aun asi nada

- [Cómo cambiar el icono de tu aplicación Android Studio](https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/cambiar-icono-aplicacion-android-studio)

Me sigue apareciendo el mismo icono que es este:

[image: android]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu `Manifest.xml` debería aparecer algo así:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

donde `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` es donde le dices cual será tu icono, `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` es el ícono en forma circular

Answer (score -4):

A si lo hice con este tutorial y me funciono.
https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/cambiar-icono-aplicacion-android-studio

Comment: Además del enlace procura poner un ejemplo